# How to embeded the media player for the streaming radio?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, media-player

I want to include the media player in the web page with streaming radio. But i cannot find any one for that what i can do??
I use the html5 audio player but it cannot supported for all browser.

```
<audio controls>
 <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
 <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/OriginalMusicPlayer.swf" width="225" height="86">
   <param name="movie" value="media/OriginalMusicPlayer.swf"/>
  <param name="FlashVars" value="mediaPath=<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/horse.mp3" />
  </object>
  </audio>
```

Comment: try jplayer, audio.js etc... for cross browser audio support

Comment: i use audio.js but it doesnot work on firefox.